# System.NullReferenceException binding to DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Please see the code below:

```
Private Sub DataGridViewBorrowedBooks_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridViewBorrowedBooks.SelectionChanged
        'DataGridViewBookDetails.DataSource = Nothing
        If DataGridViewBorrowedBooks.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim row = DataGridViewBorrowedBooks.SelectedRows(0)
        If row Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim isbn As Decimal = Integer.Parse(row.Cells("isbn").Value.ToString())

        ' Get member record from treeview control.
        Dim member = TryCast(TreeViewMembers.SelectedNode.Tag, MemberModel)

        ' Check for root node. It does not have a member record
        If member Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Locate order record
        For Each loan In member.Loan
            If loan.ISBN = isbn Then
                DataGridViewBookDetails.DataSource = loan.Books
                DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns("ISBN").Visible = False
                DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns("Title").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
                DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns("Author").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
                DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                Return
            End If
        Next loan
    End Sub
```

The exception I get is: System.NullReferenceException on the following line: `'DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns("ISBN").Visible = False`

Comment: Do you have a column called 'ISBN' in your grid (written in upper case)? If you comment the line out, do the others work?

Comment: Apparently there is no column with a key of "ISBN".

Comment: @Steven Doggart, thanks.  member.loan contains a field called ISBN.  I don't think you have to explicitly specify the column names.

Comment: If you want to do what you are doing, you do have to explicitly name the columns or you can do it the BAD way and reference by the INDEX of the column. The best thing to do is itterate through the columns and find the one bound to your FieldName and use it. I usually create a function to do that for me so the final code is no bigger than your current code.

Comment: @steve, thanks. I don't believe you have to do this binding a list to a gridview. Why do you have to when binding object to gridview?

Comment: When binding to a gridview, you have the option to autopopulate the columns, which I assume you are doing. It will create the columns at runtime but does not NAME them. When you explicitly create the columns, it will name them something in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there simply is no column which has the name `"ISBN"` in the `Columns` collection.  You'll need to change this to the actual name of the column or use an index if that is more appropriate.  To find out all of the column names you can just print them out.  It's very likely it's mapping to a name that will be very obvious once you see it

```
For Each column in DataGridViewBookDetails.Columns 
  MessageBox.Show(column.Name)
Next
```